# using a async function from another class

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I watched a tutorial in which a class `First` had a async method

another class `Second` used the `First` Class async method in there own method
it had no asynchronous elements but was marked with the `async` keyword

the `First` Class Instance was shared via Dependency Injection

I dont understand why the `async` keyword was used for the second method

I have rebuild a simple example with a parent class and a sub class
the sub class returns the async method from the parent class

using the `asyc` keyword in the sub class method does not change the outcome

Is there a deeper meaning why to use `async` keyword in this case ?

```
class OldPromise {

     promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(`print this later`), 4000)
      });
    

    async returnPromise() {
        let result1 = await this.promise1;
        console.log(result1)
        return result1
    }
}



class NewPromise extends OldPromise {

     returnOldPromise() {
        return this.returnPromise()
    }

}


const newPromiseClass = new NewPromise();

newPromiseClass.returnOldPromise()

//> print this later
```

Answer (score 0):

The `async` keyword does not need to be used in the subclass because you dont `await` anything inside it. As a rule of thumb, never use `async` without `await`. In your case, `returnOldPromise()` returns a `Promise`, no matter if it has the `async` keyword or not.